# Login not work when in put right User and password

Tags: vb.net

```
    Try
        Dim connString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("dbx").ConnectionString
        Dim cmdString As String = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserName = @UserName AND Password = @Password"

        Using conn As New OleDbConnection(connString)
             Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(cmdString, conn)
                conn.Open()
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", TextBox1.Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", TextBox2.Text)

                Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                dtRowsReturned.Load(reader)
            End Using
        End Using

        If dtRowsReturned.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            Me.Hide()
            Dim dss As New Form1()
            dss.ShowDialog()
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Account/Password is incorrect Please try again", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End If

    Catch ex As ApplicationException

        MessageBox.Show("Error: " & ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        TextBox1.Clear()
        TextBox2.Clear()
        TextBox1.Focus()
    End Try
End Sub

Private Function IsValidated() As Boolean
    If TextBox1.Text.Trim = String.Empty Then
        MessageBox.Show("Account Required.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        TextBox1.Focus()
        Return False
    End If
    If TextBox2.Text.Trim = String.Empty Then
        MessageBox.Show("Passwrd Requried.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        TextBox2.Focus()
    End If

    Return False  
End Function
```

Comment: For future reference, please take a look at the preview of your question before submitting and DON'T submit if the formatting is a mess.

Comment: A few words in a title and a chunk of code are not adequate.  You need to provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation what you're trying to achieve and how you're trying to achieve it.  If you haven't debugged your code, i.e. set a breakpoint and stepped through it line by line, do that now.

Comment: @jmcilhinney thanks

Comment: Please tell me you're not storing passwords in plain text?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn thanks you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can't see the beginning of the first method, but based on what we can see I'm guessing it checks the `IsValidated()` function before continuing. Nowhere does `IsValidated()` ever return `True`, and so the rest of the first method will never even try to run the password check. `IsValidated()` should look more like this:

```
Private Function IsValidated() As Boolean
    If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TextBox1.Text) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Account Required.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        TextBox1.Focus()
        Return False
    End If
    If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TextBox2.Text) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Passwrd Requried.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        TextBox2.Focus()
        Return False
    End If

    Return True
End Function
```

While I'm here, it's **NEVER** okay to store passwords directly in a database column. You need an additional column for a **salt** value for each user. When a user sets a new password, you pre-pend the salt value to the password, and then run a cryptographic hash (like **[BCrypt](https://github.com/BcryptNet/bcrypt.net)**) against the result. Then you can store that hash value in the database. When someone tries to login, you prepend the salt to their attempted password, run the same cryptographic hash algorithm, and compare the result with the hash value stored in the database. Anything less is really unsafe and amateurish.

And that's just the beginning. There's also memory security (ie: `SecureString`), transport security, reset processes, etc, to think about. In short, you don't want to be writing this code yourself, or in any way involved in building your own authentication system. It's just so easy to get results that *seem* to be right — even pass rigorous unit tests, but are wrong in subtle ways such that a year later you find out you were hacked six months ago. Instead, lean as much as possible on the authentication tools already provided by your platform of choice.